# Are there any tools or techniques for php to discover all classes particular class depends on?

Tags: php, oop, dependencies

Are there any tools or techniques for php to discover all classes particular class depends on ? For example to find out which classes CActiveRecord (Yii framework) class depends on (CComponent, CDbException, CHasOneRelation and so on)

Comment: The technique is called *"don't use framework which depends on global state"*. Tying to extend/replace Yii core classes must be categorized under "cruel and unusual punishment" section. Been there, done that, hated every single minute. My approach was *"edit, save, refresh, see the new fatals, repeat"*.

Comment: The question isn't related to Yii, it's related to finding PHP dependencies generally

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ReflectionClass to find out the dependencies, in particular the getParentClass() method provided.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getparentclass.php

Answer (score 0):

You could get your hands dirty and write some code to utilise ReflectionClass - or run phpdoc http://www.phpdoc.org/ on your codebase and then read the generated documents.